# How to substring in Struts2?

Tags: java, struts2, substring

How can I substring a string using Struts2 taglibs?

This is my attempt using JSTL/EL:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
...
<s:property value="firstName" />
<c:set var="string" value="${firstName} "/>
<c:out value="${fn:substring(string,0,5)} "/>
```

This does however not work. How can I achieve my requirement?

Comment: I have no idea about the Struts2 part since I don't use it. Try to replace `value="${firstName}"` by `value="somestring"`. If it works, then it's a fact that Struts2 and EL doesn't share the same scope. You'd like to use the one *or* the other, but not both.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/64825/struts2-how-to-substring-in-jsp

Comment: I suggest you to use JQuery to process your code at JSP side.

Comment: @kamaci: Re: *"I suggest you to use JQuery to process your code at JSP side."* Haha, brilliant joke. Hint: http://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference action properties using JSP EL as `${action.property}`.

```
<c:out value="${fn:substring(action.firstName, 0, 5)} "/>
```

Comment: Note that using JSTL fn:substring(), it is not necessary to check the string length. If too small, this does not give a 

StringIndexOutOfBoundsException - unlike core Java String.substring().

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that firstName is a java.lang.String then:

```
<s:property value="firstName.substring(0,5)" />
```

Comment: I think the casing is wrong but cannot edit. I think the correct is `substring`.

Comment: No - using core Java String.substring() will fail if the length of firstName is less than 5. Using JSTL fn:substring() will not fail.

Answer (score 1):

The substring function works only on the underlying Java String object and not on the s:set variable we made of it.
For example:

Suppose I have a (Action)class which contains a Java variable email. Then I can access this variable in the JSP file like this:

```
<s:set name="jspEmail" value="%{email}" />
```

If I want now to substring everything before the @, I have to do this on the Java variable AND NOT on the JSP struts variable.
So like this:

```
<s:set name="namepart" value="%{email.substring(0,email.indexOf("@"))}" />
```

and then use it like:

```
<s:property value="%{namepart}"/>
```