# Struts : How to use function:substring in <bean:write> tag

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl, el

I am using `Hashmap` to print values on jsp.

Here is my logic:

```
<%--
property="collectonRoot" is my hashmap
property="value" is my hashmap values
--%>

<logic:iterate id="element" name="viewServerFileCounterStatusForm" property="collectonRoot">                
            <tr>
                <td  class="tblrows"><bean:write name="element" property="value" />
                </td>
        </tr>
    </logic:iterate>
```

values output are like this

```
/archived/2012/3/20=1
```

This is ok, but now I want to use function with map values to get string after '=' sing means '1'. How can I do this?

thanks in advance.

Comment: i don't think it's part of struts2?

Comment: i am using struts so, overall it's part of struts application.

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [struts2: how to substring in jsp?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/64825/851811), [How to substring in Struts2?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5313206/851811)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you want last character of all the values in the map, why dont you do substring in java level in any controller class wherer you are preparing this map.Dont mind that i gave free suggestion, but in practical it is better you do your logic work in controller classes instead of JSPs. 
   Even if you still want substring code to be written in jsp then  use "" tag.

below code is to set map value in "string" variable
'<'c:set var="string" value="'<'bean:write name="element" property="value" /'>'"/>

below code is to print the substring of "string" variable.
'<'c:out value="${fn:substring(string,start,end)}"/'>'

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but never know when someone is working on some legacy code with struts 1 stuff. Like I just had to do endure.

Similar phalgun's suggestion, but instead I use ${} to access the element because I couldn't get bean:write to work in in value of c:set

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


<logic:iterate id="element" name="viewServerFileCounterStatusForm" property="collectonRoot">
  <tr>
    <c:set var="varValue" value="${element.value}"/>
    <td class="tblrows"><c:out value="${fn:substring(varValue, 0, 8)}"/></td>
  </tr>
</logic:iterate>
```